# MySQL replication, single table out of sync, can I manually copy across?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a master-slave replication solution activated. All working nicely but due to human intervention, there is inconsistency between the master-slave on a couple of tables. The replication yelled at duplication and someone casually ignored this and skipped. When I compare the master and slave, some tables have different data, or the slave is missing certain data.

I cannot restart the sync from scratch as this is a phenomenally slow connection we are working with. Seeing as there are only 2 tables that are "out of sync", can I manually dump the table from the master and manually "import" the table on the slave or will that break something I am unaware of?

Comment: This might be useful for you - https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: Hi, this tool basically recreates the same values on the master, causing the sync to reignite. Have tried something similar manually and it didn't take, we could remove the data from master, put it back in and wait for the sync to hopefully occur. If that doesn't work, would be be safe to export the table on master and then manually import it on slave thereby having same data on both or will that break something else thereby requiring an entirely new sync and recreating the slave-master database?

Comment: Yes. That would work too. I suggested pt-table-sync because you can use that to find the missing data and apply them on the slave - very useful when there are a lot of records.